# How do we know $T'(\psi_j)=\psi_j\circ T$, where $T:V\to W$, $T': W'\to W'$ is dual map of $T$, and $\psi_j\in W'$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, dual-spaces, dual-maps

Sometimes I have trouble with the notation in the book "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Axler.

Currently, my issue is with the following theorem (Theorem 3.114 in the 3rd edition book)

> Let $v_1, ..., v_n$ be a basis of linear space $V$,
> $\varphi_1,...,\varphi_n$ be a basis of $V'$, the dual space of $V$.
>
> Let $w_1, ..., w_m$ be a basis of linear space $W$, and $\psi_1, ...,
> > \psi_m$ be a basis of $W'$.
>
> Let $L(V,W)$ denote the linear space of linear maps from $V$ to $W$.
>
> Suppose $T\in L(V,W)$ and $T'\in L(W', V')$ (dual map of $T$).
>
> Let $M(T)$ denote the matrix of the linear map $T$ relative to the
> aforementioned bases of $V$ and $W$, and $M(T')$ denote the matrix of
> the linear map $T'$ relative to the aforementioned bases of $W'$ and
> $V'$.
>
> Then $M(T')=(M(T))^t$, where the superscript $t$ denotes transpose.

The proof of this theorem starts as follows

> Let $A=M(T)$ and $C=M(T')$.
>
> Suppose $1\leq j\leq m$ and $1\leq k\leq n$.
>
> From the definition of $M(T')$, we have
>
> $$T'(\psi_j)=\sum_{r=1}^n C_{r,j}\varphi_r$$
>
> **The left side of the equation above equals $\psi\circ T$**. Thus applying both sides of the equation above to $v_k$ gives
>
> $$(\varphi\circ T)(v_k)=\sum_{r=1}^n C_{r,j}\varphi_r(v_k)$$

**My question** is about the statement in bold above.

As far as I can tell, $T'(\psi_j)$ means that we have a linear map $T':W'\to V'$, we give it a linear map in $W'$ as input (namely the linear map $\psi_j$), and we get a linear map in $V'$ as output (ie a linear map $V\to\mathbb{R}$).

$\psi\circ T$, on the other hand is a function composition, which I believe is defined for every $v\in V$ as

$$(\psi_j\circ T)(v)=\psi_j(Tv)\tag{1}$$

This is also a linear map $V\to\mathbb{R}$.

**How do we know that $T'(\psi_j)=\psi_j\circ T$?**

Comment: I've not read Axler, but this is almost certainly the **definition** of $T'$.

Comment: concurring: it is by definition.

Answer (score 2):

After reading the comments, the answer is obvious.

We know that $T'(\psi_k)=\psi_j\circ T$ by definition of the dual map of $T$, which in Axler is

> **3.99 Definition:** dual map, $T'$
>
> If $T\in L(V,W)$, then the dual map of $T$ is the linear map $T'\in
>  L(W',V')$ defined by $T'(\psi)=\psi\circ T$ for $\psi\in W'$.